# Error: spawn ENOENT: missing the sass executable

Tags: ruby, windows, sass, gulp

I'm using bash in windows.

Getting this error when trying to run a sass compiler command via gulp.
I have Ruby & Sass installed.
Sass works fine when running it manually.

```
Error: spawn ENOENT: missing the sass executable.  Please install sass and make available on your PATH
```

I have included the directory of my ruby bin in the PATH var (system variables within Enviroment variables).

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried a reboot ?

Comment: Which command have you run to install sass ?

Comment: I used 'gem install sass' to install sass.  It worked fine with no errors

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your gulp-ruby-sass task is probably configured to execute SASS using Bundler (a gem dependency manager). When you don't have Bundler installed, that execution will fail with the error message you've quoted. Check your task configuration for the parameter "bundleExec" and make sure it's set to false, that way gulp-ruby-sass will run the SASS command directly.

Answer (score 17):

I had the same issue, fixed it by typing this;

```
sudo gem install sass
```

Answer (score 2):

A reboot didn't fix it unfortunately. 
I swapped out the gulp-ruby-sass for the gulp-sass plugin and all is working fine.

It's hardly a fix but it served as a solution for me.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of installing `ruby-sass`, I simply ran

```
npm i -g sass
```

Then replaced `"sass"` in gulp.js to `"sass.cmd"` for Windows

Answer (score 0):

For my case the error was:

```
gulp-notify: [Error running Gulp] Error: spawn sass ENOENT
```

To fix it, I did the following:

In your project root:

```
npm install --save-dev gulp-ruby-sass
```

Which installed: gulp-ruby-sass@1.0.5 node_modules/gulp-ruby-sass

Then:

```
sudo gem install sass
```